# Laying a box over an image in CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to lay a black box with opacity over the middle and right panels so that they are effectively 'grayed out'.

[image: Current display]
[image: Aim]

I can get as far as this:
[image]

Which clearly isn't quite right as the colour is behind the panels but I need it to be in front

My code is:

```
.packages_wrapper
  .packages.premium
    .dmnd
      = image_tag "premium.png"
      %h1
        PREMIUM
        %span.left_shape
        %span.right_shape
    %ul.package_list{style: 'margin-top: 45px;'}
      %li Create business listing
      %li Upload your logo
      %li Add multiple contact details
      %li Appear in searches for your region and category
      %li Write business description
    %p.price Free
    .package_after_login.premium
      = link_to 'Sign up now', new_owner_path(query: 'Premium')
  .square-box

    .packages.silver
      .dmnd
        = image_tag "silver.png"
        %h1 
          SILVER
          %span.left_shape
          %span.right_shape
      %p
        %span.small_premium_inline_icon
      %p.plusline{style: 'font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;'}  +
      %ul.package_list{style:'color: #59595c;'}
        %li Respond to reviews
        %li Add social media links
        %li Upload images and video
        %li Create detailed listing
      %p.price £99 per year
      .package_after_login#silver
        = link_to 'Sign up now', new_owner_path(query: 'Silver')
    .packages.gold
      .dmnd
        = image_tag "golden.png"
        %h1 
          GOLD
          %span.left_shape
          %span.right_shape
      %p
        %span.small_premium_inline_icon
      %p.plusline.gold_column_plus{style: 'font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;'} +

      %p
        %span.small_premium_inline_icon.silver_wrapper
      %p.plusline.gold_column_plus{style: 'font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;'} +

      %ul.package_list
        %li No competitor banner ads on your business page
      %p.price £149 per year
      .package_after_login#gold
        = link_to 'Sign up now', new_owner_path(query: 'Golden')
```

And my css includes:

```
   .square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    height: 530px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right:50px;
    float:right;
}
    .square-box:before{
    content: "";
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get it in front?

Thanks

Comment: We'd need to see a demo, but positioning the pseudo-element absolutely would be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change z-index and alpha(opacity) of the .square-box

**After OP posted example Url I have updted my answer with following HTML and CSS,**

**HTML**

```
<div class="packages_wrapper">
<div class="packages premium">
<div class="dmnd">
<img alt="Premium" src="/assets/premium-cdfcd2e49eb7f0cccdfcce365f190a11.png">
<h1>
PREMIUM
<span class="left_shape"></span>
<span class="right_shape"></span>
</h1>
</div>
<ul class="package_list" style="margin-top: 45px;">
<li>Create business listing</li>
<li>Upload your logo</li>
<li>Add multiple contact details</li>
<li>Appear in searches for your region and category</li>
<li>Write business description</li>
</ul>
<p class="price">Free</p>
<div class="package_after_login premium">
<a href="/owners/new?query=Premium">Sign up now</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="packages silver">
<div class="dmnd">
<img alt="Silver" src="/assets/silver-74195f85f4e27927f7f1e91625c5dac9.png">
<h1>
SILVER
<span class="left_shape"></span>
<span class="right_shape"></span>
</h1>
</div>
<p>
<span class="small_premium_inline_icon"></span>
</p>
<p class="plusline" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">+</p>
<ul class="package_list" style="color: #59595c;">
<li>Respond to reviews</li>
<li>Add social media links</li>
<li>Upload images and video</li>
<li>Create detailed listing</li>
</ul>
<p class="price">£99 per year</p>
<div class="package_after_login" id="silver">
<a href="/owners/new?query=Silver">Sign up now</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="packages gold">
<div class="dmnd">
<img alt="Golden" src="/assets/golden-646ae0d7f8be160135445ff17c6117be.png">
<h1>
GOLD
<span class="left_shape"></span>
<span class="right_shape"></span>
</h1>
</div>
<p>
<span class="small_premium_inline_icon"></span>
</p>
<p class="plusline gold_column_plus" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">+</p>
<p>
<span class="small_premium_inline_icon silver_wrapper"></span>
</p>
<p class="plusline gold_column_plus" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">+</p>
<ul class="package_list">
<li>No competitor banner ads on your business page</li>
</ul>
<p class="price">£149 per year</p>
<div class="package_after_login" id="gold">
<a href="/owners/new?query=Golden">Sign up now</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="square-box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.packages_wrapper {
  clear: both;
  height: 430px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.square-box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 620px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  right: 30px;
  bottom: -92px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? or a link where I can see actual working code?

Comment: in above provided link there is no black box visible to me.

Comment: No, that's the original, and I'm trying to work out how to put the box over the two right panels. I don't have a working link to my trial yet, sorry.

Comment: Please check my answer now, I have edited it after working around into the developer tool on your provided url

Answer (score 1):

it needs a higher (css) z-index than the other items

```
z-index:999
```

and maybe some opacity:

```
  opacity:.3;
```

In your example you can add the following css for a similar effect without adding more elements (it grays out the gold and silver option):

```
.packages.silver, .packages.gold {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```